# Proof verification, limit of cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$ be a random variable and let $F_X:\mathbf{R}\to\mathbf{R}$ be the cumulative distribution function of $X$.
Let $x\in\mathbf{R}$ such that $\mathbf{P}(X=x)=0$. Prove that $\lim_{y\to x^-} F_X(y)=F_X(x)$.

My try:

$F_X$ is monotone and bounded, so $\sup_{y<x} F_X(y)=\lim_{y\to x^-} F_X(y)$ exists (completeness of $\mathbf{R}$). We will show that $\lim_{y\to x^-} F_X(y)=F_X(x)$:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{y\to x^-} F_X(y) &\stackrel{1}{=}\lim_{n\to\infty} F_X(x-\tfrac{1}{n}) \\
&\stackrel{2}{=}\lim_{n\to\infty }\mathbf{P}(X\leqslant x-\tfrac{1}{n}) \\ 
&\stackrel{3}{=}\mathbf{P}\left[\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{X\leqslant x-\tfrac{1}{n}\}\right]\\
&\stackrel{}{=}\mathbf{P}(X<x)\\
&\stackrel{4}{=}\mathbf{P}(X\leqslant x) \\
&\stackrel{2}{=}F_X(x)
\end{align*}

(1): Take a sequence $(x_n)$ for which $x_n<x$ for all $n\in\mathbf{N}$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=x$, for example $x_n=x-\frac{1}{n}$.

(2): Definition of the cumulative distribution function.

(3): Continuity of the probability measure.

(5): $\mathbf{P}(X\leqslant x)=\mathbf{P}(X<x)+\mathbf{P}(X=x)$ and $\mathbf{P}(X=x)=0$.

Is this correct? Can I indeed take one sequence if I show first that the limit exists or do I need to show it for all sequences converging to $x$ but strictly less than $x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:** Your proof seems correct. This is enough to take only one sequence because you've already proven that the limit exists.

**Long answer:** The [theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Other_characterizations) attributed to Eduard Heine asserts that

> $$\lim_{x\rightarrow a^{-}}f\left(x\right)=L\Longleftrightarrow\forall\left\{x_{n}\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\:{\rm such\: that}\:x_{n}<a:\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_{n}=a\Longrightarrow\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f\left(x_{n}\right)=L$$

You have proven the left side - the limit exists. You've also found the number it is equal to

$$L=\sup_{y<x}F_{X}\left(y\right)$$

Your goal now is to show that it is also equal to something else, and for this you can use the above theorem with a sequence of your choice.